# How to combine two egdes and nodes in to one that has common starting nodes in Networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I am quite new for networkx and I am asking help from the Stackeroverflow community.

I am trying to combine nodes and edges that have a common starting node as shown below in the figure. The arrow shows the expected result.

[image: Italian Trulli]

```
nodes_to_combine = [n for n in graph.nodes if len(list(graph.neighbors(n))) == 2]
for node in nodes_to_combine:
    graph.add_edge(*graph.neighbors(node))
nx.draw(graph, with_labels=True)
```

Can anyone help me to figure out this?

Comment: Please print `edgelist` so that this can be reproduced

Comment: @yatu, thank you for your reply. Can you give me a hint how to do it with edgelist?

Comment: I mean if you could share a sample from the edgelist to make this reproducible

Comment: Do you need to change the node name, or is it okay if your new node is named, `20`?  If so, look at `contracted_nodes`

Answer (score 3):

NetworkX has no functions to merge nodes in the graph so it should be implemented manually. Here is the example without attributes merging (it can has its own logic):

```
def merge(G, n1, n2):
    # Get all predecessors and successors of two nodes
    pre = set(G.predecessors(n1)) | set(G.predecessors(n2))
    suc = set(G.successors(n1)) | set(G.successors(n2))
    # Create the new node with combined name
    name = str(n1) + '/' + str(n2)
    # Add predecessors and successors edges
    # We have DiGraph so there should be one edge per nodes pair
    G.add_edges_from([(p, name) for p in pre])
    G.add_edges_from([(name, s) for s in suc])
    # Remove old nodes
    G.remove_nodes_from([n1, n2])
```

Here is how it works:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from([
    ('0','20'),
    ('10','20'),
    ('10','30'),
    ('20','40'),
    ('30','50'),
])
nx.draw(
    G,
    pos=nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot'),
    node_color='#FF0000',
    with_labels=True
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

```
merge(G, '20', '30')
nx.draw(
    G,
    pos=nx.nx_agraph.graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot'),
    node_color='#FF0000',
    with_labels=True
)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation and example. One more question, what if the function could detect edges who share a common node by itself instead of giving nodes? From your example 20 and 30 share a common node which is 10. So that the function should find common node (10) and combine node (which is 20 and 30). 

Is that possible to do it as well? Thank you for your time.

Comment: This function just merge two nodes given in attributes. You can try to find common nodes with some loop that is iterating for graph nodes and then call this `merge` function for needed nodes. If you need some particular node triplets, you should use a particular loop (like nx.chain_decomposition, for example).

Comment: networkx does have an algorithm to merge nodes: `contracted_nodes`.  Not sure it would do everything needed here.

Comment: @vurmux I was trying to iterate using for loop and calling your function inside the for a loop.
 Can you help me if you have time? 

for n1, n2, attr in list(G.edges(data ='True')):
    
    predecessors1 = [pred for pred in G.predecessors(n1)]
    predecessors2 = [pred for pred in G.predecessors(n2)]
#check if they have similar predecessors
    if (predecessors1 == predecessors1):
        merge(G, n1, n2):

nx.draw(G, pos=nx.shell_layout(g1), node_color='#FF0000', with_labels=True)

Can you help me if you have time? I am tired of trying this for the past 24 hours? Thanks

Comment: @Joel Wow, I didn't know about this function! Thank you! But it works a bit different - it creates new graph and merge one node into another (not combining them). But anyway it is good in edges merging automation.

Comment: @Kapital You are changing the iterating graph in the loop so in some time it crashes with KeyError. You should write pairs to merge in list and then merge nodes later. But you should correctly handle situations like: "Merge 1-2 and 1-3". And after you merge 1-2, you will not have node 1, you will have node 1/2 so you should merge 1/2 - 3

Comment: @vurmux Thanks will try it.